# Non-response bias (many waves, time span between waves not consistent)

Tags: statistical-significance, bias, non-response

I want to ask regarding non-response bias. I have sent my questionnaire on-line to SMEs in Malaysia. However, I have sent reminders many times (around 5 times). However, now I cannot recall when the reminders were taken place as my account has been cancelled on the on-line questionnaire system. However, based on my guessing, I am doing ONE way ANOVA to see if there is a significant difference between the data collected based on the waves. the test shows there is a significant difference. What should I do? Am I doing what I am supposed to be doing correctly?

In short, I have data collected through many waves (around 5 waves). For your information, the time span between the waves is not consistent. all waves accumulated to 163 respondents (SMEs).

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly shouldn't do a simple one way ANOVA; because you have the same people surveyed multiple times, your errors will not be independent and that violates an assumption.

The usual course here would be (I think) a multilevel model. If you had the dates for the waves, then you could treat time as continuous. Since you do not have that information, you probably have to treat time as categorical and look at the effects of each wave.